# How to convert string with backslash to json

Tags: python, json

How do I convert this string `u'{\'name\': "User", \'valid\': False}'` to json using `.loads()`.

I get a

`*** ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

and I don't want to use `.eval()` or `ast_literals()`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...how did you end up with those backslashes ?

Answer (score 4):

This *does not look like a valid JSON* - there should be double quote strings instead of single quote strings and `false` instead of `False`. [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) would handle it as is, but if you want to use `json.loads()` you would have to fix it before loading, for this sample input:

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> s = u'{\'name\': "User", \'valid\': False}'
>>> s = s.replace("\'", '"').replace("False", "false")
>>> json.loads(s)
{u'valid': False, u'name': u'User'}
```

Note that this is not really reliable.